# Could the tezos node down for 5 minutes affects baking rights?

Tags: baking

On multiple times, we have noticed that on the cycle we have done some maintenance where we put our tezos node down for 5 minutes (refresh new code, etc) that the baking rights for the corresponding future cycle are lower.
I'm not talking about missing baking or endorsement, we did our maintenance window outside of our rights.
I'm talking about future baking rights. 
At first we thought it was just a coincidence but it has been so consistent that these cycles have lower baking and endorsement rights that we have to assume a connection. 
Could that be the case? And if so how come? This shouldn't be affecting it so I'm wondering.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The baking and endorsement rights are generated with a pseudorandom number generator, using a seed chosen for each cycle. The seed is computed by iteratively hashing the previous seed together with revealed nonces.

So, it is inconceivable that your maintenance activities affect the number of rights assigned to you. There is just no mechanism for it.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is how the baking and endorsement rights are assigned. It is just that we somehow have seen a strange correlation on cycles with short downtime. We will try to validate if there is any exception in the future. Thanks

Comment: If you provide more details (even approximate), or a description of your methodology, your statistical inference could be criticized. I'd bet your data are consistent with random rights...